# Django auth permission interfering with Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to POST something to my API from a view. My API view has a custom made permission only, where it looks for a token, and its open to Cross Site Requests. However, if I post something when I'm logged in, the request does not work, and I get a 403 error. If I log out, the request works perfectly again.

What is the problem with this? Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Analyze the 403 error, is there an error message you get back?

Comment: @niklas Yep, it says CSRF token not given, which is extremely weird since CSRF is disabled using a header.

Comment: Are you making this request from the browser (the API explorer view)?

Comment: @Symmetric nope, its from a regular view where the user is signed in.

Comment: Please provide more information if you are looking for help. What did you check already ? What is the view you're using (Django ? DRF ? APIView ? Viewset ?) ? What are the permissions and authentication scheme both on the view and in the settings ?